# How to test if a macro's value (set via kvoptions in a package) is empty or blank (e.g. using etoolbox)?

Tags: etoolbox, kvoptions

I have no idea, why this test fails and how to get it to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myTestSty.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{myTestSty}[2018/11/29 v. 1.0 myTestSty]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=@myTestSty,prefix=@myTestSty@}

\DeclareStringOption{myKey}

\def\myKey{\@myTestSty@myKey}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[%
    %myKey={Hello world!},
    myKey={} %<-- blank?
    ]{myTestSty}

\begin{document}

    myKey: --{\myKey}--

    myKey: \ifblank{\myKey}{blank}{not-blank}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three errors:

1. you have to expand `\@myTestSty@myKey` when defining `\myKey`;
2. you have to expand `\myKey` to test whether its replacement text is empty;
3. the definition of `\myKey` should go *after* processing the options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myTestSty.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{myTestSty}[2018/11/29 v. 1.0 myTestSty]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{family=@myTestSty,prefix=@myTestSty@}

\DeclareStringOption{myKey}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\edef\myKey{\expandonce{\@myTestSty@myKey}} % <--- expand

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[%
    %myKey={Hello world!},
    myKey={} %<-- blank?
    ]{myTestSty}

\begin{document}

myKey: X{\myKey}X

myKey: \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\myKey}{blank}{not-blank}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can shorten the test by defining

```
\newcommand{\ifblanke}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{#1}%
}
```

and call

```
\ifblanke{\myKey}{blank}{not~blank}
```

A different approach with `l3keys2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myTestSty.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{myTestSty}[2018/11/29 v. 1.0 myTestSty]

\RequirePackage{expl3,l3keys2e,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mytest/main }
 {
  myKey .tl_set:N = \myKey,
 }

\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { mytest/main }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfBlankTF}{smmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \tl_if_blank:VTF #2 { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF #2 { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    %myKey={Hello world!},
    myKey={} %<-- blank?
    ]{myTestSty}

\begin{document}

myKey: X{\myKey}X

myKey: \IfBlankTF*{\myKey}{blank}{not-blank}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much @egreg. Now I see.

Comment: Is it possible to shorten the test? E.g. introduce some kind of a helper-macro or wrapper that holds the expandafter ... expandafter?

Comment: @lAtExFaN Yes, I added it, together with a different approach.

Comment: Hmm, "blank" seems to be hard-coded ;-) I mean: If I comment-in `myKey={Hello World!}` the output also says `blank`? The `l3keys2e` code works fine.

Comment: @lAtExFaN That was the third error. `;-)`